# Add foreign key on existing table in Sequel Pro

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, sequelpro

I have two existing table A and B. A have 1000 rows and B have 100 rows.

I want to change one of the column on table B to be the foreign key which will reference to the the id (primary key) in table A.

However, the SQL query `alter table <table B> add foreign key (<column in table B>) references <table A>(id)` does not work in Sequel Pro, and the error message is `Cannot add foreign key constraint`.

Do anyone know why?

Comment: If the tables contains any data already then you must check that there is no data which does not match the FK which you want to create (`tableB.columnB` value which is not present in `tableA.id` values list). If such values exists then you must edit or delete (set the value to NULL or remove the row) these values, or insert them into tableA (create new row with this value). Also ensure that both columns have the same datatype precisely, and that `tableA.id` is indexed as unique column (maybe primary key).

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand this part. "then you must check that there is no data which does not match the FK which you want to create (tableB.columnB value which is not present in tableA.id values list)."

Comment: For example, in some row tableB.columnB=123 but there is no a row for which tableA.id=123.